# Im importing a data set from another (leaving out the blanks) but i want a sum of the totals to show at the bottom of the table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

ive got

```
=SORT(FILTER('Base Sheet'!$A$2:$F, 'Base Sheet'!$A$2:$A <> ""),5,False)
```

in order to import and sort from a different sheet. I now want a sum at the bottom of the table but every time i add a new data set to the origional sheet it breaks the sorted table.
I figured i needed to work out the place i want the sum to show :

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(F1:F21,MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(F1:F21),0)))
```

to locate the first blank space
i want something to the affect of =
show sum in cell

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(F1:F21,MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(F1:F21),0))))
```

any ideas how this can be achieved

i cant find a display in cell (x) kinda function

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

this outputs 5 columns:

```
=SORT(FILTER('Base Sheet'!A2:F, 'Base Sheet'!A2:A <> ""), 5, 0)
```

you can wrap it into `{}` and add row on the bottom like:

```
={SORT(FILTER('Base Sheet'!A2:F, 'Base Sheet'!A2:A <> ""), 5, 0);
 "×", "×", "×", "×", "×"}
```

every `"×"` can be exchanged to whatever you need so for example if you want to sum only B column from your formula output you can do:

```
={SORT(FILTER('Base Sheet'!A2:F, 'Base Sheet'!A2:A <> ""), 5, 0);
 "×", SUM(INDEX(FILTER('Base Sheet'!A2:F, 'Base Sheet'!A2:A <> ""),,2)), "×", "×", "×"}
```